# How can I tell if average comments-per-question/answer increased over recent years?

Tags: support, comments, statistics

Anecdotally I feel like I get more comments on SO questions, and perhaps more comments on answers to my questions, than I used to. I mean genuine discussion, essentially a forumesque behaviour.

Quite what that implies I'm not sure but memory is subjective. How can I quantify this whether on my questions, or on SO as a whole? Does SO report any statistics on such matters?

Comment: This is a tough one. While you could use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), create a query, and see that the results likely corresponds to your feeling, such a query would be heavily biased due to comments that got deleted as no longer needed. I don't know of a way to count comments including deleted comments.

Comment: @ErikA I'd not even considered deleted comments. Good point